# Height of Full Binary Tree

Tags: algorithms

How to prove the relationship between nodes n, and height h of a Full Binary Tree is
2<sup>h</sup> =(n+l)/2.

Comment: try to prove by induction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to prove the relationship is induction as noted by Mayank Deora. (The height of root is zero, actually if you define the height of root to be 1 the formula will look much more convenient, at least for me $2^h = n+1$).

For $h = 0$, the case is trivial $2^0 = \frac{1+1}{2} = 1$.

Now the step. We know that $2^{k} = \frac{n_k+1}{2}$ and if you count the number of leaves on the tree of height $k$, there will be $2^k$ of them. So $n_{k+1} =n_k+2^{k+1}$

Then $\frac{n_{k+1}+1}{2} = \frac{n_k+ 2^{k+1}+1}{2} = 2^k + \frac{n_k+1}{2} = 2^k + 2^k = 2^{k+1}$

$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$